# Why do I get the Stack Overflow exception when calling Locate method?

Tags: delphi, stack-overflow, delphi-xe7

I have a problem with a repetitive `TADOTable` lookup by using the `Locate` method. There's no problem when the following code executes for the first time, but any subsequent execution of it throws the `Stack Overflow` exception.

```
procedure TForm14.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOTable1.Open;
  if not ADOTable1.Locate('Num-permis', Edit1.Text, []) then
    ShowMessage(' Try it with another number, the figure does not exist');
end;
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop opening the table every time, or start closing it every time. The first would be my preference:

```
procedure TForm14.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if not ADOTable.Active then
    ADOTable1.Open; 
  if not ADOTable1.Locate('Num-permis', edit1.Text, []) then 
   ShowMessage(' Try it with another number, the figure does not exist'); 
end;
```

Comment: Thank you ... Can you help me programmable button is conservation if the change in the table ... only if there is no change does not conservation

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but that would be a different question and you should create a new post and ask it there.

Comment: Hm, still I'm curious what caused the reported SO. `TDataSet.SetActive`, which is internally triggered by the `Open` call has a protection for `if Active <> Value then` and you actually just put that `Active` check outside (you do this `if not Active then SetActive(True)` which then internally checks `if Active <> True then PerformOpen`). I know that what you say is correct, just cannot find a reason in code.

Comment: procedure TForm14.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if (adotable1.state in [Dsedit,dsinsert]) then
begin
AdoTable1.post;
showmessage('Saved successfully');
end;
end;

Comment: this button is true or non

Comment: As I said, **create a new question**. This one is about a stack overflow exception and has been answered.

Comment: @TLama: Not sure why it happens (in code) either... I'll try to find time to take a look.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem stack overflow ... when I do a search and update, and save the update ... and when I repeat the search process emerges card  stack overflow ... which then closes the program